# How To Read Arrays In API Using Ajax And Jquery

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, api

I am creating a ticket reservation system. So , in this system I used API to request and get(response) data. But , when I got the response from API , it contains arrays of arrays.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "flight-offer",
      "id": "1529553187230--523715719",
      "offerItems": [
        {
          "services": [
            {
              "segments": [
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "CMB",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T03:15:00+05:30"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T05:50:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "6369",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "77W"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "6369"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT5H5M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "N",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "NLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T06:35:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "4",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T12:00:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "7007",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "77W"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "7007"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT7H25M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "N",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "NLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "2",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T14:15:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "DUB",
                      "terminal": "2",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T15:40:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "5965",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "320"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "EI",
                      "number": "5965"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT1H25M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "N",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "NLRCAS"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "segments": [
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "DUB",
                      "terminal": "2",
                      "at": "2018-07-20T18:00:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "2",
                      "at": "2018-07-20T19:20:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "5978",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "320"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "EI",
                      "number": "5978"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT1H20M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "S",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "SLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "4",
                      "at": "2018-07-20T21:55:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-21T06:40:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "7014",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "359"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "7014"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT6H45M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "S",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "SLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-21T07:35:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "CMB",
                      "at": "2018-07-21T15:20:00+05:30"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "6366",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "77W"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "6366"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT5H15M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "S",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "SLRCAS"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "price": {
            "total": "837.46",
            "totalTaxes": "464.46"
          },
          "pricePerAdult": {
            "total": "837.46",
            "totalTaxes": "464.46"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "flight-offer",
      "id": "1529553187230--1553108626",
      "offerItems": [
        {
          "services": [
            {
              "segments": [
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "CMB",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T03:15:00+05:30"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T05:50:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "6369",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "77W"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "6369"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT5H5M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "N",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "NLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T06:35:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "4",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T12:00:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "7007",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "77W"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "7007"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT7H25M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "N",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "NLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "5",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T14:15:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "DUB",
                      "terminal": "1",
                      "at": "2018-07-02T15:40:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "830",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "320"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "BA",
                      "number": "830"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT1H25M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "S",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "NLRCAS"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "segments": [
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "DUB",
                      "terminal": "1",
                      "at": "2018-07-20T16:30:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "5",
                      "at": "2018-07-20T18:00:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "829",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "321"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "BA",
                      "number": "829"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT1H30M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "S",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "SLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "4",
                      "at": "2018-07-20T21:55:00+01:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-21T06:40:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "7014",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "359"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "7014"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT6H45M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "S",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "SLRCAS"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "flightSegment": {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "DOH",
                      "at": "2018-07-21T07:35:00+03:00"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "CMB",
                      "at": "2018-07-21T15:20:00+05:30"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "BA",
                    "number": "6366",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "77W"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "QR",
                      "number": "6366"
                    },
                    "duration": "0DT5H15M"
                  },
                  "pricingDetailPerAdult": {
                    "travelClass": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareClass": "S",
                    "availability": 9,
                    "fareBasis": "SLRCAS"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "price": {
            "total": "837.46",
            "totalTaxes": "464.46"
          },
          "pricePerAdult": {
            "total": "837.46",
            "totalTaxes": "464.46"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now I want to read and display these values in the view page. I mean I want to get and display type and id number. Then I tried below steps with laravel. I got all the details with

> Console.log(data);.

But, couldn't get any thing into the view page. How can I get values to the view page ??

View page.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Origin City : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="origin" value="" id="origin"> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Destination City : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="destination" value=""
                                              id="destination"> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Adults : <select name="st" class="form-control" id="adults">
                        @for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++)
                            <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                        @endfor
                    </select> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Departure Date :<input class="form-control" type="text" name="departureDate" id="departureDate">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Return Date :<input class="form-control" type="text" name="returnDate" id="returnDate">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Access Token : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bat" value="" id="bat"> <br>
                </div>

                <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn">Pull User Data</a>

                <p id="errorModal"></p> <br>

                <div id="ghapidata" class="clearfix"></div>

            </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function(e){

                        var origin = $('#origin').val();
                        var destination = $('#destination').val();
                        var departureDate = $('#departureDate').val();
                        var returnDate = $('#returnDate').val();
                        var adults = $('#adults').val();
                        var bat = $('#bat').val();

                        var requri   = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=' + origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&departureDate=' + departureDate + '&returnDate=' + returnDate + '&adults=' + adults;
                        var repouri   = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=' + origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&departureDate=' + departureDate + '&returnDate=' + returnDate + '&adults=' + adults;

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=' + origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&departureDate=' + departureDate + '&returnDate=' + returnDate + '&adults=' + adults,
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data);

                                requestJSON(requri, function(JSON) {

                                        // else we have a user and we display their info
                                        var data   = JSON.data;
                                        var type   = JSON.type;
                                        var id = JSON.id;
                                        var iataCode     = JSON.iataCode;

                                        var outhtml = '<h2>'+data+' <span class="smallname">(@<a href="#" target="_blank">'+type+'</a>)</span></h2>';
                                        outhtml = outhtml + '<p>User Type: '+type+'</p></div>';
                                        outhtml = outhtml + '<p>Id: '+id+' - IATA Code: '+iataCode+'<br></p></div>';
                                        outhtml = outhtml + '<div class="repolist clearfix">';

                                        var repositories;
                                        $.getJSON(repouri, function(JSON){
                                            repositories = JSON;
                                            outputPageContent();
                                        });

                                        function outputPageContent() {

                                                outhtml = outhtml + '<p><strong>Repos List:</strong></p> <ul>';
                                                $.each(repositories, function(index) {
                                                    outhtml = outhtml + '<li><a href="#" target="_blank">repositories[index].data.type</a></li>';
                                                });
                                                outhtml = outhtml + '</ul></div>';

                                            $('#ghapidata').html(outhtml);
                                        } // end outputPageContent()

                                }); // end requestJSON Ajax call


                            },
                            error: function (jQXHR) {
                                // If status code is 401, access token expired, so
                                // redirect the user to the login page
                                if (jQXHR.status == "401") {
                                    $('#errorModal').modal('show');
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                                    $('#divError').show('fade');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    function requestJSON(url, callback) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            complete: function(xhr) {
                                callback.call(null, xhr.responseJSON);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
            </script>
```

Comment: does javascript not need the "global" tag inside its functions? (calling "repositories" from the function without parsing it nor declaring it a global), Also, (havent toyed with this on javascript, only php so may be wrong)

 consider the response an object, you have to do iterative handling for each sub section (painful I know). 

so from what i can see. calling the "type" would be JSON.data.type as its within the "data" array

Comment: @CraigB - I dont know lots of things about JS.. :/

Comment: if you `console.log(JSON);` it gives you "object"?

Comment: Yes , I got the response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to parse the response as JSON, then  handle it from there:
 `JSON.parse(data)`

```
 $.getJSON(repouri, function(data){
     repositories = JSON.parse(data);
     data = repositories.data;
     type = data.type;
     id = data.id;
     services = data.offerItems.services; // Referencing the sub objects within
     outputPageContent();
 });
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rhn9cweg/19/

gotta address the sections, can put it into a looping function to handle it a bit cleaner, but you need to parse the data to the function .

---- EDIT ----

to loop through each of the fields:

```
$.each(repositories, function (key, data) {
    console.log(key);
    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
        console.log('index', data);
    });
});
```

put that to a function and the call it on it self for using an if block to see if the item is an object.  (call the function from within the function for a recurring check)

Comment: can you fix the dump of the json object so its the complete response then I can tinker correctly, currently its docked before the end and I can't do a fiddle

Comment: I have no idea about this. I mean I am very new to this field.. :/

Comment: in your original question, where you pasted the JSON dump (data etc etc) its not the complete response, you've cut it short. Please update it with the complete response so that I can do testing for you.

Comment: How can I show all the database results continuously ?? I have updated the API with 2 response.

Comment: I've added a foreach loop to get the information, where it has console.log just adjust what you want it to do, I'd suggest putting it to a function where you pass the object ( `function objectLoop(object) { }`) and have that loop inside of that with it returning the keys and values as an array, then you can loop through the array it returns and put that information into your fields.

Comment: If you can , please check this one and answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177669/how-to-solve-this-array-error-in-rest-api Thank You..

Answer (score 1):

The field type, id are inside data in json array format so you can't read that directly using JSON.type or JSON.id

```
 var data   = JSON.data;
 var type   = data[0].type;
 var id = data[0].id;
 var iataCode     = data[0].iataCode;
```

Please check browser console for error messages to debug  your code

Comment: It says TypeError: data is undefined. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: On which line.? just click on the error, it will take you to the code line

Comment: This line - var type   = data[0].type;

Comment: I got the type and id. But , didn't get the iatacode. How can I get it ??

Comment: in your JSON provided you're not recieving iatacode